# delete rows for a dependency table

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have one table: USERID which contains the ID and USER NAME relationship.
And I have one table for each USER which will store various information for that user. In each USER table, a "user_id" column is defined as foreign_key using USERID.id and default "RESTRICT" setting is used.

The problem is, somehow I duplicated USERID rows for additional 2 times. Meaning, if correct rows are 1000, now I have 3000 rows in USERID.

I want to delete the meaningless 2000 rows. But it's extremely slow since it will check all child tables which are thousands of them.

One solution I could think of is just hard record the rows of USREID as 1000 and ignore the 2000 additional values. I've updated all tables to use only first 1000 row IDs of USERID.

The answer I'm looking for is:

1. Is it necessary to remove the 2000 additional rows in dependency table USERID?
2. How to speedup the deletion process?

Comment: I'm wondering if this is one of the key difference between SQL and NoSQL? Will NoSQL see this kind of issues?

Answer (score 0):

So far the best answer I got from somewhere else is to delete the foreign_key for every table, update the table with foreign_key as column, add foreign_key with updated table.

It's slow but will not hang.